# Contact form submitting twice

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I added a pop up form for email subscription and it is sending twice on submission and the confirmation message is also being displayed twice

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#contact").submit(function(e) {      

        e.preventDefault();                

        var emailval  = $("#email").val();

        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

        if(mailvalid == false) {
            $("#email").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(mailvalid == true){
            $("#email").removeClass("error");
        }


        if(mailvalid == true) {
            // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
            // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
            $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmessage.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! You have signed up for a trial. A member of our team wil soon be in contact :)</strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1700);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to write this line:

```
$("#contact").submit(function() { return false; }); // Remove this
```

You can remove this line:

```
 $("#send").on("click", function(){     // Remove this
```

And write this instead:

```
$("#contact").submit(function(e) {      // Add this

    e.preventDefault();                 // Add this

    var emailval  = $("#email").val();

    var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

   /* Other code */

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

It didn't work at first and i was looking around online earlier and seen a few people putting e.stopImmediatePropagation(); under e.preventDefault(); and that worked for me.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Please be sure to vote up and accept the answer if it solves your issue. :)